# Puppeteer & Chromium using large CPU?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I have a nodejs script running on my Macbook 24/7, and every 20 minutes or so it runs Puppeteer to parse the contents of a website. Every two days, the fan gets very loud, and I see Chromium is using lots of CPU and RAM. Is there someway I can fix this?

This is the code I am running:

```
const options = {
                args: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                    '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
                    '--no-first-run',
                    '--no-zygote',
                    '--single-process', 
                    '--disable-gpu'
                ],
                headless: true
            }

const browser = await puppeteer.launch(options);

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36')

await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });


await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', (req) => {
if(req.resourceType() === 'stylesheet' || req.resourceType() === 'font' || req.resourceType() === 'image'){
    req.abort();
 } else {
      req.continue();
  }
});

await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });


// ... do stuff

await page.close();
await browser.close();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1) this "fan gets very loud" phenomenon happens only when your puppeteer schedule happens? (2) if you visit the same website manually with chrome on the same Macbook is it consuming the same resources?

honestly, I don't know what happens within the "`// ... do stuff`" section, but I don't think puppeteer could eat so many resources in normal conditions, it is not the best for your machine, especially if you are running it 24/7 only due to this task. **wouldn't running this job from Github Actions, Heroku, etc. would be an option in your case?**

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea to automatically kill and launch puppeteer every 20 minutes. Puppeteer browser (chromium) will automatically closed when scrape/parse job finished, and then after 20 minutes, it will relaunch fresh new browser, so it wont eat more resources.
I'm using browser pool (cluster) for this method.

```
import cluster from 'cluster'
import * as os from 'os'
import * as process from 'process'
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

const launchOptions = {
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process',
        '--disable-gpu'
    ],
    headless: true
}

let lastProcessUptime = []
let userAgentString = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'
let viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 }
let CPUsNum = os.cpus().length
CPUsNum = 1 // Set this number as how many browser page do you want to launch simultaneously

const runThis = async (processID) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions)
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent(userAgentString)
    await page.setViewport(viewportSize)
    await page.setRequestInterception(true)
    page.on('request', (request) => {
        let blockedResources = ['stylesheet', 'font', 'image']
        if (blockedResources.includes(request.resourceType())) {
            await request.abort()
        } else {
            await request.continue()
        }
    });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
    // ... and do stuff
    // ... then close the page and browser and also kill the process
    await page.close()
    await browser.close()
    lastProcessUptime.push({
        pid: process.pid,
        uptime: Math.round(process.uptime() * 1000)
    })
    process.kill(processID)
    process.exit(0)
}

if (!cluster.isWorker) {
    console.log(`Primary ${process.pid} is running`)

    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < CPUsNum; i++) {
        cluster.fork()
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`) /*with code: ${code} and signal ${signal}*/
        setTimeout(() => cluster.fork(), (20 * 60 * 1000) - lastProcessUptime[lastProcessUptime.findIndex(process => process.pid === worker.process.pid)].uptime) //lets recreate the worker that died
    })
} else {
    let processID = process.pid
    console.log(`Worker ${processID} started`)
    ;(async (processID: number) => {
        await runThis(processID)
    })(processID)
}
```